# Complex number to fractional power

Tags: complex-numbers

I am trying to write $(-i)^\frac{1}{2}$ in the form $c=a+ib$ where $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$.

I am using De Moivre's formula and have $\cos(\frac{3\pi}{4}+\frac{k\pi}{2})+i\sin(\frac{3\pi}{4}+\frac{k\pi}{2})$.

I am not sure if this gives me a principal argument of $\frac{3\pi}{2}$ or $\frac{3\pi}{8}$. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A principal argument $\phi \in (-\pi, \pi]$. This implies that of the two possibilities you mentioned, only $\phi = \dfrac{3\pi}{8}$ works. In other words, $c = 3\cos \frac{3\pi}{8}+3i\sin \frac{3\pi}{8}$. Note here that there are a total of $4$ solutions to this equation, but if you are looking for a solution with a principal argument, then the $\phi = \dfrac{3\pi}{8}$ does the job !

Answer (score 0):

The $n$-th complex root is not unique, and hence it doesn't make sense to talk about *the* principal argument here.

For instance, you have
$$(-1)^{\frac 12}=\pm \mathrm i,$$
both roots may be written as
$$\cos\frac\pi 2+\mathrm i\,\mathrm\sin \frac\pi2$$
and
$$\cos\frac{-\pi} 2+\mathrm i\,\mathrm\sin \frac{-\pi}2.$$

Both arguments are principal.